# CSS Path location not working for image

Tags: css

I have tried to link a path for an image in my CSS several different ways but it won't work is there anything that I'm missing?

```
background:src="C:\Users\simcity\Documents\HTML\Header.jpg";
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to set a background image.

In that case

```
background: url('C:Users/simcity/Documents/HTML/Header.jpg');
```

would be the appropriate method.

Comment: Yes - w/o the "src" looks better.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you must not use local paths, but else URL paths so for example:
`background:src="C:\Users\simcity\Documents\HTML\Header.jpg";` might be:
`background:src="Header.jpg";` if your image resides at the same level of your html document  or `background:src="/path/to/your/html/and/img_folder/Header.jpg";` if the image is in another folder (the folder must be at the same level of your html)

**EDIT:**
is *background:url('path for the image')* not *background:src="path for the image"*

Answer (score 0):

I think the CSS syntax what you are looking for:

```
#id {
    background: url("C:\Users\simcity\Documents\HTML\Header.jpg");
}
```